# Datagridview row color which contents color in C#

Tags: datagridview, row, backcolor

i have a question about datagridview row color. there are records on my DGV fetching data from sql. i have a column like answer and it keeps data like Yes or No. i wish in DGV the columns value if yes: the row bg color is red or the coloumns value if no; the row bg color is blue. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++ )
 {

    if ((string)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == "Yes")
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. so which event of DGV i will write this code DataBindingsComplete?

Comment: and i will add; some coloumns are NULL and when converting it gives error like this converting System.DBNULL to string

Comment: if `DBNULL` row also show back red right? then check the condition values isnot dbNull and values equal to Yes

Comment: im checking and converting NULL VALUES coming from sql if(!Convert.Is.DBNull(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value)) {//bla //bla} but it gives me error like cant convert system.DBNull to string.??